# sum of ONLY POSITIVE variable in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have variables `$var1, $var2, $var3`. Each day they are being fetched from a MYSQL query and being displayed in a row in a table. Sometimes they are positive and sometimes there are negative values. I would like one column to show the sum of only the POSITIVE values. How do I write a php statement to add only the positive values?
Do I need to write 6 if statements or is there an easier way?

Comment: if greater then 0 then positive, if less then 0 then negative

Comment: I know that, but I needed help in writing the statements. The answer below was very helpful, I was trying with if() statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [PHP Ternary Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to do it with 4 lines of code.

Simply, if variable is greater than zero, positive (add to sum), else negative (skip, no need to add).

Use ternary operator.

```
<?php
$sum = 0; // Initialise $sum
$sum += ($var1 > 0) ? $var1 : 0; // If $var1 is greater than 0, add to $sum.
$sum += ($var2 > 0) ? $var2 : 0; // Same as of $var1
$sum += ($var3 > 0) ? $var3 : 0; // Same as of $var1
?>
```